# Configuration of Sonicwall Load Balancing

Tags: vpn, load-balancing, sonicwall

We installed a Sonicwall NSA 240 appliance and have configured it up for our SSL VPN connection and for load balancing with 2 ADSL lines. Over the past week, I have been testing the load balancing options to optimize the connection speeds for our users - but I've run into the following:

Round Robin load balancing is the ideal load balancing setting and it's roughly doubling our throughput- but, when it's active users are unable to access any SSL enabled websites such as banking, web-mail, etc. For this reason, I have been using percentage based balancing as it allows me to enable source and destination IP binding, which doesn't 'break' any secure connections but were left with the slow connection speeds we had before adding the second line.

I'm looking for a method in which we can take advantage of the round robin connection speeds while allowing users to access sites with SSL certificates, all while still allowing our remote (vpn) users to connect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options you could use to achieve this. My preference would be to add in a routing policy that always sent https traffic through a specific interface unless it failed.

There is I think another option that can allow for "sticky" sessions which will keep those created on one interface always going through the same interface, thus fixing your issues as well.

If we can be of help - http://www.sosonicwall.com

Comment: So far so good with the routing policy...
Cheers!